# Do we have a site where I may ask farming and animal husbandry questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wanted to ask questions about poultry, animal husbandry and farming practices.

Is there a site for those questions?

Comment: An Agriculture Site would be excellent! Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 4):

**Construction** related topics like chicken coops, etc are suitable for [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com). See some existing questions on [chicken coop](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=chicken+coop), [farming fence](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=farming), etc.

Some **academic** topics would be suitable for [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com).

Examples: [Physiology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology), [reproduction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproduction), [pharmacology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmacology), etc.

---

Edit: A site on [Agriculture](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124848/agriculture?referrer=MmJjZjc2M2Q1N2QzMTJlODFiZTAzMDQxNDU2ZWFjZTY4NmVjNTJjMDA1MzY3YjJhYzNhYWI4YjA2ZWQ0ZjQwMswio4ud9Zn3fhWCrWbH4nxMc0-FJDg1dgaJoB6XELYV0) has been proposed in Area 51. If it succeeds in becoming a site, it would be suitable to ask there. If you like it, you may follow it and contribute some example questions.

Comment: Hey Severus, can you link a few related tags and their info so people get a better idea?

Comment: @Ollie Thanks, I have added some. In the first para, I have added links to search keywords. In the second para, as I mentioned before, those would be helpful for academic questions. Animal husbandry is a full time course in many universities.  I have added some of the tags of essentially what are taught in university. There could be more. I have added what I know.

Answer (score 3):

[Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) might be a good bet.  They have a [farming tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) there, but it has no usage guidance, so check out [questions tagged with it](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) and containing [certain keywords](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/search?q=chicken+pork).